# Can not connect to MySQL Server by 127.0.0.1

Tags: mysql, ubuntu, localhost

I'm using Ubuntu 12.04 32bit AND  MySQL Server 5.5.31

I can connect to MySQL Server with following command successfully :

```
$ mysql -u root -p -h localhost
```

But when i'm using `127.0.0.1` instead `localhost` can not connect :

```
$ mysql -u root -p -h 127.0.0.1
```

The error is :

```
ERROR 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on '127.0.0.1' (111)
```

Any ideas would be awesome.

Comment: are you installed your server properly..

Comment: I have installed `lamp-server` package. This package install MySQL automatically.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe the allowed host for root is 'localhost' and your host doesnt map 127.0.0.1<->localhost correctly?

Try setting the host for this user to 127.0.0.1 or % (allow ALL ips to connect)

Comment: Yes your right. I have changed `bind-address` to this `bind-address = 127.0.0.1` in `my.cnf`. It works fine. Thank You

Answer (score 1):

Have you uncommented the my.cnf's line

```
skip-networking
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check this http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/can-not-connect-to-server.html for a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Update `my.cnf` file to include the following line

```
bind-address=128.2.177.192
```